# This code isn't displaying the correct answer

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

```
dictionary = open('dictionary.txt','r')
def main():
    print("part 4")
    part4()
def part4():
    naclcount = 0
    for words in dictionary:
        if 'nacl' in words:
            naclcount = naclcount + 1
    return naclcount
main()
```

basically it comes with the answer 25 which is right, except when I put another function in before part 4, it will print as 0.

```
def part1():
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    vowelcount = 0
    for words in dictionary:
        words = words.lower()
        vowelcount = 0
        if len(words) == 8:
            if 's' not in words:
                for letters in words:
                    if letters in vowels:
                        vowelcount += 1
                if vowelcount == 1:
                    print(words)
    return words
```

Comment: In the other function that you are putting in, are you using the 'dictionary' variable also?

Comment: Yeah, should I just open the file in each function?

Comment: I would like to see the code for "another function" please.

Comment: Alright, i edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably pass the filename as an argument to the part4 function, then create a new file object, because when you iterate through it once, it will stop returning new lines.

```
def main():
    dict_filename = 'dictionary.txt'
    print("part 4")
    part4(dict_filename)


def part1(dict_filename):
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    vowelcount = 0
    dictionary = open(dict_filename,'r')
    for words in dictionary:
        words = words.lower()
        vowelcount = 0
        if len(words) == 8:
            if 's' not in words:
                for letters in words:
                    if letters in vowels:
                        vowelcount += 1
                if vowelcount == 1:
                    print(words)
    return words

def part4(dict_filename):
    dictionary = open(dict_filename,'r')
    naclcount = 0
    for words in dictionary:
        if 'nacl' in words:
            naclcount = naclcount + 1
    return naclcount

main()
```

Also, if you want to be able to use your script either as an imported module or standalone, you should use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_filename = 'dictionary.txt'
    print("part 4")
    part4(dict_filename)
```

in place of the `main` function

Comment: or you can simply `dictionary.seek(0)` to move the pointer to the start of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your another function. The problem is unclear unless you show your another function.

From what I inferred by your question and code. I have modified (clean) your code. See if it helps.

```
def part4(dictionary):
    words = dictionary.readlines()[0].split(' ')
    nacl_count = 0
    for word in words:
        if word == 'the':
            nacl_count += 1
        #print nacl_count
    return nacl_count


def part1(dictionary):
    words = dictionary.readlines()[0].split(' ')
    words = [word.lower() for word in words]
    vowels = list('aeiou')
    vowel_count = 0
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == 8 and 's' not in word:
            for letter in words:
                if letter in vowels:
                    vowel_count += 1
        if vowel_count == 1:
            #print(word)
            return word


def main():
    dictionary = open('./dictionary.txt', 'r')
    print("part 1")
    #part1(dictionary)
    print("part 4")
    part4(dictionary)


main()
```